# accessing specific elements in a class HTML

Tags: html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to get the contents only of the name of the product and its seller. I do not want description or feeedback.

```
  <div class="m-l-50 col-md-7 ">
      <span class="font-size-15 " style="vertical-align:top"><strong>How to fix hdd</strong></span><br>
      <span>Seller: bestbuy</span><br>
      
      <span>Description: This Method will show you how to </span><br>
      
     Feedback:<strong> <span style="color: green;"> 74 </span> :  <span style="color: red;">1 </span><br>
```

******MY CODE******

```
def scrape_this_page(page_source):
    page_source=BeautifulSoup(page_source,"html.parser")

    products = page_source.findAll(class_='m-l-50 col-md-7')

    for product in products:
        names.append(product.span[0])
    for product in products:
        sellers.append(product.span[1])
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and post there expected output? Maybe share the URL?

Comment: @JotkanwalSingh Which are the desired text for **product** and **seller**, which text are you looking to extract?

Comment: I want a dic that would have a product with its seller and so on.

Comment: product- how to fix hdd, seller-bestbuy

Answer (score 2):

In selenium just use -> for example: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(div.some_class_name.another_class_name)`

And in BeautifulSoup use `page_source.select(div.some_class_name.another_class_name)`

If you dont have any classname you have to iterate (for loop) over the elements and check if the text starts with "Seller" or access it with Indies (elements[0]) (may be unstable)